# How to draw a moving line in an image

Tags: c#, gdi

I am trying to draw a horizontal line on the white rectangle corresponding to the cursor position on it.

```
public static void CreateMapHistoGramModifiedByColourBar(int LineYindex)
{
    float[] dashValues = { 1, 1, 1 };
    Pen blackPen = new Pen(Color.Black, 1);
    blackPen.DashPattern = dashValues;
    Point P1 = new Point(0, LineYindex);
    Point P2 = new Point(RefBarWidth, LineYindex);
    using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(Image.FromFile(WaferMapHistogramFileName)))
    {
        g.DrawLine(blackPen, P1, P2);
    }
}
```

The above code does not seem to be doing anything to the saved image. How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Judging on this line:

> the above mentioned code does not seem to be doing anything to the saved image

It sounds like you want to draw a line on the image and then save that new image back out. At the moment all you are doing is loading in an `Image` object, drawing on that and then discarding of it:

```
using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(Image.FromFile(WaferMapHistogramFileName)))
{
    g.DrawLine(blackPen, P1, P2);
}
```

Note that the `Image` class also implements `IDisposable` so you should be disposing of it.

Put all this together and you should get something like this:

```
using (Image image = Image.FromFile(WaferMapHistogramFileName))
using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(image))
{
    g.DrawLine(blackPen, P1, P2);

    image.Save(@"Save somewhere, here: WaferMapHistogramFileName?");
}
```

Note that saving the image back at `WaferMapHistogramFileName` will overwrite the original.

---

Side note; from this line:

> corresponding to the cursor position

Your drawing a line on the image judging by the position of the cursor on it. If this is the case you should make sure you are offsetting the cursor position as that will give you its location on the `Screen`, `Form` or `Control`.

Answer (score 0):

Use 
`Cursor.Position.Y` and `Cursor.Position.X` to get the position of the mouse *on the screen*. You can then offset these to account for where on the form your white rectangle is.

If you are wanting this line to refresh as you move the mouse, tie a redraw/repaint event to the mouse move event `MouseMove`. If this is all being drawn within a `PictureBox` use `pictureBox1.InitialImage = null;` first before redrawing

Comment: Firstly nothing suggests the user is using `Cursor.Position` they could be using `MouseEventArgs` which will give them `Form` or `Control` relative positions, though they should still need to offset the location. Also please never use an event other than `Paint` to draw otherwise you will lose all changes to the image if the form minimises or similar. You can store positions in a variable and draw them in `Paint` instead.